# Database: Relation between Orders and Items

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

One article explains:

> One-to-Many
>
> “One given order can possibly contain many items. One given item
>   belongs to one and only one order.”

Here, "given item" means one specific item ? Because we can have multiple quantity of that particular item in stock .
But I am thinking it this way:

> An item has many orders and an order contains many items.

So isn't it many to many relationship ?

Below is my orders table:

```
+------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL              |       |
| customerId | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL              |       |
| itemId     | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL              |       |
| quantity   | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL              |       |
| date       | timestamp    | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |       |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
```

Items table:

```
    +------------+---------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field      | Type          | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+------------+---------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| name       | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| price      | decimal(10,2) | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| stock      | int(11)       | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| supplierId | int(11)       | YES  | MUL | NULL              |                |
| date       | timestamp     | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
+------------+---------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what I do is that I take it as  *orders -> order_items -> items*. An Order can has many Order Items and every Order Item is belongs to a Item.

the tabe stucture should be

`orders`

- id
- customer_id
- date

`order_items`

- id
- order_id
- item_id
- qty
- price

`items`

- id
- name
- price
- stock
- supplierId
- date

And in the code you can do something like this

**App/Order**

```
class Order extends Model {

   public function orderItems(){
      $this->hasMany(OrderItem::class);
   }
}
```

**App\OrderItem**

```
class OrderItem extends Model{

    public function order(){
      $this->belongsTo(Order::class);
    }
    public function item(){
      $this->belongsTo(Item::class);
    }
}
```

**App\Item**

```
class Item extends Model{

    public function orderItems(){
      $this->hasMany(orderItem::class)
    }

}
```

hope this help!

PS - follow table_name_singular_id naming convention as foreign key names in order for the laravel eloquent to work without passing column names

Answer (score 1):

there isn't many to many relationship in database. if should there is it should be done using bridges relationship. as per you database table shows it still shows one to many relationships. a particular order may contain many items, therefore table order should generate its own unique entity. but it also contain foreign entity of item id, in which many item id were in there. therefore one table order id for many table item id.

Comment: Many to Many relationship can be achieved using Pivots in Laravel.

Comment: @VaishnavMhetre pivots is literally a bridge entity.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say i have the following objects :-

Orders : A and B
Items : X, Y and Z

Now Order A might contain multiple quanties of items X but each distinct item x will have a unique serial number.

So, if order A has 3 quantities of items X, in reality it ontains 3 different items with the same name but different manufacturing id/serial number like

item X with Serial number 1
item X with Serial number 2
item X with Serial number 3

And they are all linked to Ordex A which has a unique serial number.

A good example of a many to many relationship would be an employee and a team in an orgrnization where employees work as part of multiple teams.

Answer (score 1):

As you might know many to many relationship can be achieved using **Pivot** table.

Definitely it will be a **many to many relationship** only if you store the quantity of items as a value in **Pivot** table.

The schema can be as follows -

*Order*

- id
- name

*Item*

- id
- name

*Pivot*

- order_id
- item_id
- quantity